# How to covert a list of values into boolean true false

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

I am new to python and wanted to see if I could get some help on how I can convert a list of values into booleans.

I have a list:

```py
lst = [-10.4, -33.6, -1.2, -11.4, -1.1]
```

I am trying to define a function that will go through `lst` and assign `True` if the number is equal to or less than -10, and `False` if the number is greater than -10.

Expected output:

```py
lst: [True, True, False, True, False]
```

Down below is the code I attempted to write but didn't retrieve the results I wanted:

```py
def covert_to_boolean(lst):
    for num in lst:
        if num >= -10: 
            return True
    else: 
        False 
        return lst
```

Input:

```py
covert_to_boolean(list_1)
```

Output:

```py
True
```

Comment: `result = [num <= -10.0 for num in lst]`

Comment: as it's tagged numpy: `np.array(lst)<=-10`

Comment: Is this really a list, and do you want a list result?  If so, why the `numpy` tag?

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = [-10.4, -33.6, -1.2, -11.4, -1.1]

out=[i<=-10 for i in lst]

print(out)
#[True, True, False, True, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the list like `for num in range(len(lst))` and with the same if condition, just set `lst[num] = True` or `lst[num] = False`

it would look like the following

```
for num in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[num] >= -10:
        lst[num] = True
    else:
        lst[num] = False
```

Comment: Yup, except you would use the assignment operator = instead of the equal ==

Comment: You want `<=` not `>=`. Also, you can get rid of the if-else and just do `lst[num] = lst[num] <= -10`

Answer (score 1):

```
def covert_to_boolean(lst):
    return_list = []
    for _, num in enumerate(lst):
        if num >= -10: 
            return_list.append(True)
    else: 
        return_list.append(False)
    return return_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `map()`:

```
list_1 = [-10.4, -33.6, -1.2, -11.4, -1.1]

def covert_to_boolean(lst):
    return [*map(lambda i:i<=-10,lst)]

print(covert_to_boolean(list_1))

# [True, True, False, True, False]
```